# Hibernate DDL wrong @JoinTable Primary Key with @OrderColumn

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I'm using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and I have this entity:

```
@Entity
public class Person extends Subject
{
    ...

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "PERSON_ACCOUNT", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID") , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_ID") )
    @OrderColumn(name = "PERSON_ORDER")
    private List<Account> accountList = new ArrayList<>();

    ...
}
```

and Hibernate generates this SQL:

```
create table PERSON_ACCOUNT (PERSON_ID bigint not null, ACCOUNT_ID bigint not null, PERSON_ORDER integer not null, primary key (PERSON_ID, PERSON_ORDER)) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

but, IMO, the PK is incorrect.
PK should be:

```
primary key (PERSON_ID, ACCOUNT_ID)
```

Is this a bug (EclipseLink generates correct PK)?

Is there a way (or a workaround) to make Hibernate generate correct PK?

Note that **I don't want to generate DDL on my own**.

Thanks

Comment: why should the PK of the join table *not* include the order? A List can have duplicates of an element.

Comment: That's right, but I don't want duplicate PERSON_ID, ACCOUNT_ID too. Maybe it should be `primary key (PERSON_ID, ACCOUNT_ID, PERSON_ORDER)`?

Comment: or maybe I should add a unique contstraint.

Comment: If you don't want duplicate PERSON_ID, ACCOUNT_ID then you don't use a List that allows dups ... i.e pick a List implementation that doesn't allow them (SortedSet?) or do as you say with unique constraint (but that only takes effect at persist). And it is incorrect to say that EclipseLink generates a correct PK, because it is totally wrong ... it is prohibiting dups

Comment: Guess you're totally right... please post your comments as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PK of a join table for a List using order column should always have `PERSON_ORDER` as part of the PK since a *List* should allow dups.

If you don't want duplicate `PERSON_ID, ACCOUNT_ID` combos then you don't use a List that allows dups ... i.e pick a *List* implementation that doesn't allow them (*SortedSet*?) or do as you say with unique constraint (but that only takes effect at persist so maybe not the most efficient).

It is incorrect to say that EclipseLink generates a correct PK, because it is totally wrong ... it is prohibiting dups, and so useless for most *Lists* (even though the field is a List).

Comment: Thanks, now I undertstand the problem. But *Sets* (LinkedHashSet) are not allowed with *@OrderColumn*, I think I'll go with both custom List and unique constraint.